# Kendo UI - Opt Group in Select List

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm working with Kendo UI, and am looking to have a opt groups in my select list. The html to do this is:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Options 1">
     <option>Option 1.1</option>
     <option>Option 1.2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Options 2">
     <option>Option 2.1</option>
     <option>Option 2.2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

What is the kendo equivelent for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think kendo is providing this functionality as of now...

see below given links....

http://www.telerik.com/forums/optgroup-support-

but here is an example to achieve this

http://www.sambeauvois.be/blog/2014/02/optgroup-with-the-kendo-ui-combobox/

thanks

Comment: Please also include the essential information from the links. Link only answers are considered "not real" answers and can be deleted.